# Sorting the vector of std::pair

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, struct

I need to define a comparator function for vector sorting:

```
   class Sched
    {
    public:
    struct Op
    {
      // some data
    };
    typedef std::pair<Op*,Clk> OpSchedule;
    void genSched() { std::sort(m_mappedOp.begin(),m_mappedOp.end(),cmp)}

    private:
    std::vector<OpSchedule> m_mappedOp;
    bool cmp(const OpSchedule& l,const OpSchedule& r)
    {
      return l.second< r.second;
    }
```

I get compilation error:

```
function call missing argument list; use '&Sched::cmp' to create a pointer to member.
```

Can someone advise how to solve that and what is the reason for the error?
Thanks

Comment: @jogojapan Regarding your answer: I think it's useful for the asker (and other people who find this question) to have multiple answers that say the same thing in different ways. Sometimes it helps them understand it to read it twice.

Comment: @sftrabbit Yeah.., but in this case... our answers are just too similar (and mine was 6 sec faster only because I had actually forgotten to include the word `static` in the code).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cmp` is a non-`static` member function. It must be called on some object. To get a pointer to that member function you would need to do as the error says, `&Sched::cmp`, but you would then need to bind it to some object of type `Sched`<sup>†</sup>.

However, there is no reason for `cmp` to be non-`static` so just change it to this:

```
static bool cmp(const OpSchedule& l,const OpSchedule& r)
{
  return l.second < r.second;
}
```

Then you can pass it as you are doing now.

<sup>† You could do that with `std::bind(&Sched::cmp, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)`, to bind the member function to `this`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to a make the cmp function outside the class and inside the namespace of the class so the

```
    void genSched() 
    { 
       using namespace <classNmaespace>;
       std::sort(m_mappedOp.begin(),m_mappedOp.end(),cmp)
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain how the namespace mechanism works here, or why it's necessary?

Comment: the problem with having the cmp function inside the class is that to access the cmp function the sort method must create an object to access it. Now if the cmp method is in the global scope (like a c function ) it can be accessed by the sort method without an object

Comment: Making the sort method global is not a good idea .it breaks c++ encapsulation. so it must be inside the namespace of the class .so the code would be something like std::sort (m_mappedOp.begin(),m_mappedOp.end(),namespacename::cmp)

Comment: What do you mean by "the namespace of the class"?

Comment: i was assuming your class is inside a namespace . example namespace schedule { class xyz }

Comment: Ah, I see. So you mean "the namespace in which the class is defined". And you assume that `genSched()` is not defined inside that same namespace, so you add a `using namespace` declaration. It would be great if you could explain all these things in the answer...